# Intersection of Intervals of sets

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, define $A=[-k,k]$ and $B=[x-k,x+k]$. Find $A\cap B$. 
 My attempt: For the case $0\leq x \leq2k$. i computed $A\cap B=[x-k,k]$. Also for the case $2k \leq x$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Now for the cases $2k \leq x \leq 0 $ and $x\leq2k$. I dont know what to do.
Any help and hints would be appreciated. Need Help!!!

Comment: Hint: notice that the problem is symmetric with respect to the origin, by which I mean the problem is "the same" if you reflect it across the origin. Draw some pictures, and see if you can use your (correct) previous computations to do the remaining cases.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is the "closed ball" centered on $0$ with radius $k$. $B$ is the "closed ball" centered on $x$ with radius $k$. Closed balls with same radius intersect if and only if the distance of their centers is less or equal to twice the radius.

In our case it means $\vert x \vert \le 2k$.